# How can I read a large number of files with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask, dask-dataframe

Number of file : 894
total file size : 22.2GB
I have to do machine learning by reading many csv files. There is not enough memory to read at once.

Comment: What sort of machine learning? Many algorithms particularly neural network-based models use batch learning so don't need to load the entire file into memory, and generally don't use pandas

Comment: I'm going to use a supervised learning algorithm.

Comment: I need to learn 894 files, but I am thinking about how to efficiently load them.

Comment: Yes but there's loads of different supervised learning algorithms, that's a generic term. If you don't have enough memory to load the entire dataset then you need to pick one that implements batched data loading.

Comment: To improve your question: surely your task is not to *read* your files. What is actually your task?

Answer (score 2):

Specifically to load a large number of files that do not fit in memory, one can use [`dask`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/):

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('file-*.csv')
```

This will create a lazy version of the data, meaning the data will be loaded only when requested, e.g. `df.head()` will load the data from the first 5 rows only. Where possible `pandas` syntax will apply to `dask` dataframes.

For machine learning you can use `dask-ml` which has tight integration with `sklearn`, see [docs](https://ml.dask.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can read your files in [chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas) but not during the training phase. You have to select an appropriate algorithm for your files. However, having such big files for model training mostly means you have to do some data preparation first, which will reduce the size of the files significantly.